# Getting Error on Heroku. Failed to launch chrome

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer

```
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053282+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053298+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053301+00:00 app[web.1]: (chrome:44): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:09:57.031: cannot open display:
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053303+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053305+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053308+00:00 app[web.1]: TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053310+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053312+00:00 app[web.1]: at onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:348:14)
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053314+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess. (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:338:60)
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053317+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:215:7)
2019-12-06T16:09:57.053319+00:00 app[web.1]: at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
2019-12-06T16:10:26.921203+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/product/new?search=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FHamilton-Beach-Set-n-Forget-6-Quart-Slow-Cooker-Model-33969%2F16913518" host=arcane-wave-04024.herokuapp.com request_id=34a979c5-a553-4ba2-b233-af91b577d74a fwd="124.29.252.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

I got this error. I have already setup following:
puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });

Added: https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack
to Buildpacks.

Can any one help me out in this. Code was working fine on local host. But when I deploy it on heroku, it gives this error constantly.

Comment: Have you checked **all** the Heroku-specific items in the link in that error message? https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku

Comment: I have check every thing that I can understand. If something is missing, please correct me.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with puppeteer and Heroku. I installed the same build pack which you have mentioned and i used the following code and now its working fine.

```
puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']})
```

**P.S** :  I deployed again after installing build pack.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this github repo to my heroku buildpack worked for me

https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

[image]